# How to redraw dynamic variables java

Tags: java

How can I redraw variables that get updated, for example I am testing the following code

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     Dimension d = this.getPreferredSize();
     g.setFont(font);
     g.setColor(Color.red);
     String temp;
     int [] test = {0,4,2,3,4,5};


    for(int i = 0;  i < test.length; i++)
    {
        temp = Integer.toString(test[i]);
        g.drawString(temp, (50+(i*10)), 50);

    }
}
```

The code draws the contents of the array (converting it to strings). What i want to do is update the array and repaint the new array as its being updated. I've been searching around for examples and have not been able to solve this simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want the component to redraw itself you need to invoke:

```
repaint();
```

on the component.

You would not define the Array in the paintComponent() method. Instead you would need to add a method like

```
public void setArray(int[] numberArray)
{
    this.numberArray = numberArray;
    repaint();
}
```

Then you would define a class variable "numberArray". The paintComponent() method would access that class variable.

Comment: -1, setters shouldn't do more than change properties.  Let your controller do the update.

Comment: @marvo, look at the Swing source code. Components are responsible for reapainting, revalidating themselves when a property is changed. This is like doing a setText(...) on a JLabel. You let the setText() method do the painting so you the programmer don't have to.

Comment: But doing so in setters invites complications.

Comment: @Marvo Look at the source code, this is the way Swing was designed to work. If you don't do the repaint, the programmer is likely do forget to invoke the repaint() and the component won't change.

Comment: I obviously did the repaint in my answer.  I remain convinced that it is a fundamentally bad practice to make setters do more than set a property.  The Swing coders have different requirements than application programmers do.

Comment: Exactly. by overriding the paintComponent() method of a Swing component you are creating a custom component and therefore you should follow the Swing guidelines of making sure the component is smart enough to revalidate/repaint iself when a property that affects the look of the component is changed. I already stated that a Swing component (which is what we are talking about here) is different than a business object.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  Change

```
 int [] test = {0,4,2,3,4,5};
```

to

```
int [] test = getTestData();
```

Then provide the following:

```
private int [] testData = new int [0];

private getTestData() {
    return this.testData;
}

private setTestData(int [] newData) {
    this.testData = newData;
}
```

Now to set up varying tests, try

```
setTestData((int []){0, 4,2,3,4,5});
repaint();
setTestData((int []){1,2,3,4,5});
repaint();
. . .
```

Something like that.

Comment: -1, a component should be responsible for repainting itself when one of its properties change.

Comment: He's just looking for a way to test it.

Comment: Right, so you code the method the way I demonstrated 5 minutes earlier.

Comment: Setters shouldn't do more than change the properties.

Comment: Yes, they should. Look at the source code to see how Swing works. This is a custom Swing component (because you are doing custom painting), not a business object.

Comment: It can still be the same object.  In this case, as the OP mentions, it's just for testing.  But the object could be set up to listen to something else, in which case the method that's invoked upon a data change would a) invoke the setter, and b) invoke repaint.

Comment: Look at the Swing source code to see how it is done for a JLabel. A JLabel actually does revalidate() and repaint() because of course the label can resize based on the new text.